# Controlling React JS component from vanilla Java Script code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using webpack to bundle a simple React JS component to use in plain JavaScript code. However, it does not work as expected. Here is the code:

File `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  isMobile,
  isFirefox,
  isChrome,
  isEdge,
  withOrientationChange,
} from "react-device-detect";


export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 0
    };
    this.start.bind(this);
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() { }

  start() {
    console.log("Starting ...");
    this.setState({step: 1}, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });

  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    document.addEventListener(
      "start",
      function () {
        this.start();
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  render() {
    let {step} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Current step: {step}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("my-element"));
```

File `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path:'./.env'});

const webpack = require('webpack');

const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;


module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  mode: "production",
  entry: [
    "babel-polyfill",
    "./src/App.js"
  ],
  watch:true,
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
   
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        
        terserOptions: {
          ecma: undefined,
          parse: {},
          compress: {},
          mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
          module: false,
          // Deprecated
          output: null,
          format: null,
          toplevel: false,
          nameCache: null,
          ie8: false,
          keep_classnames: undefined,
          keep_fnames: false,
          safari10: false,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "this",
    filename: "./my-bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/build"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react",
            { "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"] }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        test: /\.css$/
      },
      
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".webpack.js", ".js"]
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": dotenv.parsed
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    
  ],

};
```

File `index.html`:

```
...

<body>
<div id="my-element"></div>

<script src="./static/my-bundle.js"></script>
</body>

...
```

The screen shows `Current step: 0`, which is normal. I want to create an App instance or access the instance which is already rendered on the screen through plain JavaScript code and control its behaviour, something like this:

```
var app = new App();

// this should change the state.step to 1
app.start()
```

However, the state does not change and the screen is not re-rendered after I run this code. Meanwhile, if I find another way to trigger the start function, e.g via event listener, it works as expected.

```
var event = new CustomEvent('start');
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I am not expert of React JS or JavaScript so I did not understand deeply why the first approach does not work but the second one does. Could anyone give me a thorough explaination and show me how to achieve my goal (controlling the React JS component and treating it as a normal JS class).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `var app = new App();` you are trying to instantiate a class component, a behavior that is not supported by React. If you need to control state outside of React see [useSyncExternalStore docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useSyncExternalStore).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Asplund, I found a solution to this. It turns out all I need is `ref`. ***Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.** (from React JS official documentations)*

Instead of initiating a class App and using it in JS code, I need to declare a `ref` inside React code for later use. It looks like this:

File `MyApp.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      step: 0
    };
    this.start.bind(this);
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() { }

  start() {
    console.log("Starting ...");
    this.setState({step: 1}, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });

  }

  render() {
    let {step} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Current step: {step}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

File `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {MyApp} from "./MyApp";

export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {    
    return (
        <App ref={MyApp => { window.MyApp = MyApp }} />
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("my-element"));
```

Now I can access and control the `MyApp` component in JS code:

```
MyApp.start()
```

and it works as expected (the state is updated succcessfully).